# Finding the Errors to a System of Non-Linear Equations

Tags: error-propagation

I have a system of three non-linear equations, each with a solution that has error associated with it. It looks something like this:

[image]

Solving the system of equations should produce an error for the variables x, y, and z, but I do not know how to properly do that. I have seen a few other posts involved systems of linear equations and how to solve them, but I do not think their case matches mine.

I have tried solving the system of equations by hand and performing error propagation through the entire process, but I get different error values depending on the order I solve the equations.

Comment: You can make the equations linear by expressing them in terms of the vector $\beta=(x,xy,xz)^\prime.$ Writing the errors as the vector $\epsilon$ with standard deviations $(\sigma_f,\sigma_g,\sigma_h)^\prime,$ they become $$(f,g,h)^\prime=\pmatrix{1&-18/5&-80/7\\1&-21/10&365/14\\1&39/10&155/14}\beta+\epsilon.$$This is a (weighted) ordinary least squares regression, about which you may consult thousands of posts here on CV.